# Tensorflow kernel gets killed automatically due to over consumption of RAM (both on local machine and Google Colab)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

**Description :**

I am trying to run the PointNet Point cloud segmentation algorithm on the ready made dataset available in this repository : https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet.git

Inside an ipython notebook (on Jupyter Lab or Colab), I ran the following commands to reproduce the error :

```
!git clone https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet.git
cd pointnet/sem_seg/
!sh download_data.sh
!python train.py --log_dir log6 --test_area 6
```

As you can see the data is getting downloaded from their own download script and I am not modifying their script in anyway. But when I run their script, the tensorflow API consumes all of the available memory and then the kernel gets killed. The detailed error messages attached below :

```
tcmalloc: large alloc 3477749760 bytes == 0xdc31c000 @  0x7fecb71fc1e7 0x7fecb2fa4d51 0x7fecb3009a84 0x7fecb3009bc3 0x7fecb30a9ade 0x7fecb30aa344 0x7fecb30aa492 0x4f8925 0x4f98c7 0x4f6128 0x4f9023 0x6415b2 0x64166a 0x643730 0x62b26e 0x4b4cb0 0x7fecb6df9b97 0x5bdf6a
(23585, 4096, 9)
(23585, 4096)
tcmalloc: large alloc 2992029696 bytes == 0x1b13e2000 @  0x7fecb71fc1e7 0x7fecb2fa4d51 0x7fecb3009a84 0x7fecb3009bc3 0x7fecb309718a 0x7fecb30975d8 0x4f9ba9 0x4f6128 0x4f9023 0x6415b2 0x64166a 0x643730 0x62b26e 0x4b4cb0 0x7fecb6df9b97 0x5bdf6a
(20291, 4096, 9) (20291, 4096)
(3294, 4096, 9) (3294, 4096)
...
...
...
...
...
**** EPOCH 000 ****
----
tcmalloc: large alloc 2992029696 bytes == 0x7feb5a4c4000 @  0x7fecb71fc1e7 0x7fecb2fa4d51 0x7fecb3009a84 0x7fecb3009bc3 0x7fecb309718a 0x7fecb30975d8 0x4f9ba9 0x4f7a28 0x4f876d 0x4f98c7 0x4f7a28 0x4f876d 0x4f98c7 0x4f7a28 0x4f876d 0x4f98c7 0x4f6128 0x4f9023 0x6415b2 0x64166a 0x643730 0x62b26e 0x4b4cb0 0x7fecb6df9b97 0x5bdf6a
^C
```

I tried a lot of suggestions given to similar issues on Stackoverflow and got no resolution. In particular I tried the following :

1. Reduce the default batch size
2. Change the default optimizer (adam to momentum)

However, none of these suggestions helped me solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update :**

A self contained ipython notebook is attached in this link : [Colab Notebook](https://gofile.io/?c=uXYlNT)

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the failure you observe.

Comment: I have attached it in the updated description.